# neo4j : Limited queries sent in java

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

For a website developed under Tomcat, I connect my program to a database neo4j. Connection is done through jdbc.
My program is right now local, and the database is on a remote server.
When I start Tomcat, it first check if specifics nodes are presents, and if not, it creates them.
There are about 135 nodes.
Problem : After about ten, the program stops, and stay in something like an infinite loop.
I assume I should close something, but what?
Here is my code :

```
private ResultSet sendCommand(String command) throws SQLException
    {
        try(Statement statement = _neo4jConnection.createStatement())
        {
            return statement.executeQuery(command);
        }
    }
```

and a function to call this code (all functions are based on the same structure)

```
public static Long createNode(NodeLabel labelName)
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = getInstance().sendCommand("CREATE (n:"+labelName+") RETURN id(n)");
            Long result= rs.next()?rs.getLong("id(n)"):null;
            rs.close();
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Funny, I've dealt with exactly the same issue today. Will try some experiments with pooling e.g. via tomcat's jdbc-pool and report back.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for the support :) Do you think, we should habe to open and close the connection for each statement(or at less after a specific number?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to regularly disconnect and reconnect to the database (After about 20 statements). This is awful, but it works.
Well, however, I gave up with jdbc for neo4j, too much issues, and catastrophical performances (about 1s to get one simple data), what occures still more issues!

Anyway, Thanks for your help

Niko

Answer (score 0):

in my latest experiment I reused the same statement multiple times, not sure that is the best way but it seems to work good, too.

https://github.com/peterneubauer/blogs/tree/master/csv_jdbc, code at https://github.com/peterneubauer/blogs/blob/master/csv_jdbc/src/test/java/org/neo4j/jdbctest/JDBCTest.java

Comment: Hi Peter
Thanks, but not even possible to think about it. Almost all my statements are different, at less in the specific data (id of node, conditions ...)